# Use Promise.all to expedite the excution of one asynced and one synced tasks - async await syntax

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

let's say I got three functions :

Asynchronous function - `asyncF()` - for example , it calls a REST API.

Synchronous function `sync()`

And executer function  `exec()` which invokes them both as fast as possible , preferably in parallel .

I want `exec()` to be written using the "Async-await" syntax, without using the "Callbacks" or  "Promises" syntax .

Does it make sense to write it as :

```
async exec(){
const [res1, res2]= await Promise.all([asyncF(), sync()])
...
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: JavaScript works in only one thread so nothing is really parallel. But `Promise.all` should be fine here

Comment: You cannot run a synchronous function in parallel with anything. Why bother? Is it really a slow cpu-consuming function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const p = asyncF();
const syncResult = sync();
const asyncResult = await p;
```

Start the async task, then run the sync function, then wait for the promise to resolve.

If the sync task takes longer, there would be no extra wait async one, as the promise will have resolved:

```js
function sync() {
  const end = new Date();
  end.setSeconds(end.getSeconds() + 3);
  //loop for 3 seconds
  for (let now = new Date(); now < end; now = new Date());
  
  return 2;
}

function asyncF() {
  //after 1 seconds return the value 40
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 40));
}

async function exec(){
  const p = asyncF();
  const syncResult = sync();
  const asyncResult = await p;
  
  return syncResult + asyncResult;
}

const start = new Date();
exec()
  .then(result => console.log(`result after ${new Date() - start}ms was: ${result}`));
```

If the async task takes longer, then there is an extra wait for the promise to resolve:

```js
function sync() {
  //return immediately
  return 2;
}

function asyncF() {
  //after 3 seconds return the value 40
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000, 40));
}

async function exec(){
  const p = asyncF();
  const syncResult = sync();
  const asyncResult = await p;
  
  return syncResult + asyncResult;
}

const start = new Date();
exec()
  .then(result => console.log(`result after ${new Date() - start}ms was: ${result}`))
```

This assumes, of course, that the async task is properly asynchronous. An async function will still be executed synchronously until it reaches an `await` or ends.

---

### On errors

Do note that async rejections should still be handled if that is a risk. The problem here is that if `sync()` fails, then the `await p` would never be reached, thus a code like

```
const p = asyncF();
try {
    const syncResult = sync();
    const asyncResult = await p;

    return syncResult + asyncResult;
} catch (error) { /* do something */}
```

will not properly handle the rejection coming from `p`.

For this we can take apage from [`Promise.allSettled()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) and safely wrap the promise results into an object with a `status` that tells whether it was fulfilled or rejected:

```
const p = asyncF()
    .then(value => ({ status: "fulfilled", value }))
    .catch(reason => ({ status: "rejected", reason });
```

This can further be encapsulated into small helpers:

```
const wrapPromise = p =>
    p.then(
        value => ({ status: "fulfilled", value }), 
        reason => ({ status: "rejected", reason })
    );

const unwrapPromise = p =>
  p.then((result) => {
    const {status, value, reason} = result;
    
    if (status === "fulfilled")
      return value;
    else if (status === "rejected")
      throw reason;
    
    throw new Error(`Unknown status ${status}, the value of the promise was ${result}`);
  });
```

Using `const bar = wrapPromise(foo)` would prevent unhandled promise rejections by handling them and `await unwrapPromise(bar)` will then trigger the failure to happen at that point when it can be handled:

```
const p = wrapPromise(asyncF());
try {
    const syncResult = sync();
    const asyncResult = await unwrapPromise(p);

    return syncResult + asyncResult;
} catch(error) { /* do something */ }
```

Thus if `sync()` fails first, there is no extra unhandled promise rejection going to happen later:

```js
const wrapPromise = p =>
    p.then(
        value => ({ status: "fulfilled", value }), 
        reason => ({ status: "rejected", reason })
    );
const unwrapPromise = p =>
  p.then((result) => {
    const {status, value, reason} = result;
    
    if (status === "fulfilled")
      return value;
    else if (status === "rejected")
      throw reason;
    
    throw new Error(`Unknown status ${status}, the value of the promise was ${result}`);
  });

function sync() {
  const end = new Date();
  end.setSeconds(end.getSeconds() + 1);
  //loop for 1 seconds
  for (let now = new Date(); now < end; now = new Date());
  
  throw new Error("sync() failed");
}

function asyncF() {
  //after 3 seconds reject with error the value 40
  return new Promise((_, reject) => setTimeout(reject, 3000, new Error("asyncF() failed")));
}

async function exec(){
  const p = wrapPromise(asyncF());
  try {
    const syncResult = sync();
    const asyncResult = await unwrapPromise(p);

    return syncResult + asyncResult;
  } catch(error) {
    throw new Error(`exec() failed because: ${error.message}`);
  }
}

const start = new Date();
exec()
  .then(result => console.log(`result after ${new Date() - start}ms was: ${result}`))
  .catch(error => console.error(`error after ${new Date() - start}ms was: ${error.message}`));
```

While if `sync()` succeeds after `asyncF()` has failed, that is still OK, since the `await unwrapPromise(p)` will be the point where an exception will be raised:

```js
const wrapPromise = p =>
    p.then(
        value => ({ status: "fulfilled", value }), 
        reason => ({ status: "rejected", reason })
    );
const unwrapPromise = p =>
  p.then((result) => {
    const {status, value, reason} = result;
    
    if (status === "fulfilled")
      return value;
    else if (status === "rejected")
      throw reason;
    
    throw new Error(`Unknown status ${status}, the value of the promise was ${result}`);
  });

function sync() {
  const end = new Date();
  end.setSeconds(end.getSeconds() + 3);
  //loop for 3 seconds
  for (let now = new Date(); now < end; now = new Date());
  
  return 2;
}

function asyncF() {
  //after 1 seconds reject with error the value 40
  return new Promise((_, reject) => setTimeout(reject, 1000, new Error("asyncF() failed")));
}

async function exec(){
  const p = wrapPromise(asyncF());
  try {
    const syncResult = sync();
    const asyncResult = await unwrapPromise(p);

    return syncResult + asyncResult;
  } catch(error) {
    throw new Error(`exec() failed because: ${error.message}`);
  }
}

const start = new Date();
exec()
  .then(result => console.log(`result after ${new Date() - start}ms was: ${result}`))
  .catch(error => console.error(`error after ${new Date() - start}ms was: ${error.message}`));
```

---

The async failure can be handled more simply if a fallback value is fine:

```
const p = asyncF().catch(error => {
    //optionally do something with error

    return -1; //fallback value
});
```

Then the `await p` will simply produce `-1` on a failure.

Comment: This forgets to also handle exceptions from the synchronous task. If `asyncF()` rejects and  `sync()` throws, even if the caller catches the synchronous exception you'll still get an unhandled rejection that will crash your app.

Comment: @Bergi I initially left the exception handling as an exercise to the reader but you're right that it might not be obvious what can go wrong.

Comment: "*`try`/`catch` can be used to handle errors coming from either function call*" - the problem is precisely with this kind of code: it won't handle errors coming from **both** functions. One must indeed install the `.catch(…)` handler *before* calling `sync()`.

Comment: @Bergi you're right, I did miss that. I re-wrote the entire section on error handling.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really run two things in parallel

And it also depends on how your async function work, here async function will block an entire thread for almost a second:

```js
exec()

async function exec() {
  const startTime = Date.now()
  const [res1, res2] = await Promise.all([asyncF(), sync()])
  console.log('finished', Date.now() - startTime, 'ms')
}

function asyncF() {
  console.log('start async')
  return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    let i = 100000000;
    let x = 0
    while (i--) {
      x += Math.random()
    }
    return 'async'
  })
}

function sync() {
  console.log('start sync')
  return 'sync'
}
```

About the question in the comment:

What `Promise.all` really do here is replace a `map` function

```js
exec()

async function exec() {
  const values = await Promise.all([sync(), sync(), sync()])
  console.log(values)
  
  const values2 = [sync, sync, sync].map(fn => fn())
  console.log(values2)
}

function sync() {
  return Math.random()
}
```

Is it better? No

Is it faster? Also no

Comment: "You can't really run two things in parallel" -- sure you can. That's the point of async code.

Comment: JavaScript will stop the execution of one part of the code for a moment to handle the other one. It's not parallel. Asynchronous for sure, but not parallel

Comment: Maybe you're just referring to sync code, but you can definitely run multiple async calls in parallel, e.g. `Promise.all([fetch(), fetch(), fetch()])`. What do you mean by parallel if not this? The "async" code shown here isn't actually async. It's a blocking busy loop, not a network or subprocess call, so it makes no sense for it to be async. Almost certainly, that's not OP's use case.

Comment: When you call fetch it's the browser which handles parallel stuff. When the response comes back microtask queue handles the response in a single shared thread. My code is `async` it's just not parallel