# Promise.allSettled but used as Promise.all

Tags: typescript, promise, overloading, variadic-tuple-types

I want to create some generic handling for Promise.allSettled

Currently allSettled returns list of fulfilled and rejected results. I don't care and I really don't want to make handling everywhere of it.
I want to use it same as Promise.all
if any error, reject, BUT wait till all ends. It's important.

```
private async allAndWait<T>(values: Iterable<PromiseLike<T>>): Promise<T[]> {
    const allSettled = await Promise.allSettled(values);
    const rejected = allSettled.find((promise) => promise.status === 'rejected') as PromiseRejectedResult | undefined;
    if (rejected) {
        throw rejected.reason;
    }
    return allSettled.map((promise) => (promise as PromiseFulfilledResult<T>).value);
}
```

Created something like this but it does not allow me to send array of different type of promises. And return type is only of the first type, while I want to have exactly the same as with Promise.all experience

[image]

Comment: Do you need something like `unwrapPromise` defined in [my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74734407)? The `wrapPromise` is designed to maximally the same as what you get from `Promise.allSettiled`, so `unwrapPromise` is straight applicable to either the result of `Promise.allSettled` or the output of `wrapPromise`.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I see you just want the correct signature for `allAndWait` so the result accurately represents the input.

Comment: Please post ALL code as text and not as image ...

Comment: typescript seems to create `(Promise<number>|Promise<string>)[]` as type for the array instead of `Promise<number | string>[]`. And then the `Iterable` just uses the first of this types,which leads to errors later on. As a (admittedly quite clumsy) workaround, you could provide the types for your `T` yourself. Ie something like `await this.allAndWait<number | string>(...)`

Comment: @derpirscher I think the intention is to avoid workarounds and wants to use the same thing as `Promise.all` already does. Since that does produce matching results.

Comment: @VLAZ definitively ... Then why not just grab the signature of  `Promise.all` from the tpyings and use it for `allAndWait`

Comment: @derpirscher I put the image for clearly seeing the typings once I call it. Also, I've used exactly same typings, copied that from lib.es2015.iterable and it's jsut not working. Somehow it starts to expect all elements in the array of same type.
Maybe I should ask for typing the array of different arrays as method params and returning array of same types remaining order. Just as Promise.All do. And I'm on the unknown territory here because something that is working for es is not working for me

Comment: You should copy the signature of `Promise.all` which is in `lib.es2015.promises` ...

Comment: Btw, you should probably throw an [`AggregateError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AggregateError) if there's multiple `PromiseRejectedResult`s, not just rethrow the first one and discard the rest.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR:

```
async function allAndWait<T extends readonly unknown[] | []>(values: T & Iterable<PromiseLike<unknown>>): Promise<{-readonly [key in keyof T]: Awaited<T[key]>}>
async function allAndWait<T extends PromiseLike<unknown>>(values: Iterable<T>): Promise<Awaited<T>[]>
async function allAndWait<T extends readonly unknown[] | []>(values: Iterable<PromiseLike<unknown>>): Promise<any> {
  const allSettled = await Promise.allSettled(values) as PromiseSettledResult<Awaited<T[number]>>[]
  const rejected = allSettled.find((promise) => promise.status === 'rejected') as PromiseRejectedResult | undefined;
  if (rejected) {
      throw rejected.reason;
  }
  return allSettled.map((promise) => (promise as PromiseFulfilledResult<Awaited<T[number]>>).value)
}
```

Here is my hopefully comprehensible process:

I don't know why but in your code `T` doesn't get inferred correctly. I'd have expected that the `T` to be a union of all types that the input tuple has (so `string | number`). We can do this by shifting the type deceleration to the generic. (just shifting `PromiseLike<unknown>` would be enough).

```
async function allAndWait<T extends Iterable<PromiseLike<unknown>>>(values: T) ...
```

This admittedly doesn't help us much, as we need T to be a tuple and not a union. As you want the return types to be ordered (and not all of them being typeof the union of all input types). Whether we get such a tuple in the form of `[PromiseLike<string>, PromiseLike<number>]` or `[string, number]` doesn't matter much, as we can pluck the types from the former with a mapped type. So assuming we have such a (PromiseLike) tuple `T` we can simple do:

```
{[key in keyof T]: Awaited<T[key]>}
```

My first intuition was to use a rest operator:

```
async function allAndWait<T extends Promise<unknown>[]>(...values: T): Promise<{[key in keyof T]: Awaited<T[key]>}> {...}

allAndWait(Promise.resolve("qwe"), Promise.resolve(2)) // typeof Promise<[string, number]>
```

Note that we had to drop the `Iteratable` over an array. As we cannot use the rest operator on `Iteratable`s. Note that `Iteratable`s do not tuple like types. So we cannot say that the first element is typeof string and the second one typeof number, which we need here. We can later do a overload for this use case (in case you really need it) and provide a less powerful type implementation that works with unions. But first we need to fix that you cant even pass in arrays. You could do it like this:

```
const arr = [Promise.resolve("string"), Promise.resolve(2)]
allAndWait(...arr)
```

But this doesn't strictly follow your requested type implementation. Note that we cannot just omit the rest operator from the function decleration, as this would again convert the tuple to a union type. So we have to apply a trick:

```
async function allAndWait<T extends readonly unknown[] | []>(values: T & Iterable<Promise<unknown>>): Promise<{-readonly [key in keyof T]: Awaited<T[key]>}> {...}
```

We require two things here via a intersection type: first, `values` must be typeof Iterable<Promise>. And second, we infer a very generic tuple `T`, so that we can use it later for the export. This line is heavily inspired by the `Promise.all` type declaration and I don't know why here: `T extends readonly unknown[] | []` the union with `[]` is necessary, but it is.

This only leaves the less powerful overload for `Iteratable`s:

```
async function allAndWait<T extends PromiseLike<unknown>>(values: Iterable<T>): Promise<Awaited<T>[]>
```

Which we have to put **below** the other overload, as it is more generic and would conform to all possible inputs (so the other overload would never be reached).