# Type return value of function to be an array of the return values of input array of functions

Tags: typescript, async-await, promise

I'm trying to write a method that essentially acts as a shim for `Promise.allSettled`, and behaves like `Promise.all`.

The function takes in a list of Promises (whose return types may or may not be strongly typed), runs `Promise.allSettled` on them, and returns an array of the results mapped to either the resolved value (if resolved), or `null` if not. But I want to guarantee that each item in the result array is strongly typed to the return value of its respective promise in the input array (or unknown if the promise is not strongly typed).

Here's a simplified version of what I have so far:

```
type Task<T> = (...args: any) => Promise<T>

/**
 * Takes in a list of promises, and runs them in parallel
 * If the promise resolves, return the value
 * If the promise rejects, log the error and return null
 */
export async function runTasks<T>(tasks: Array<Task<T>>) {
  const results = await Promise.allSettled(tasks)
  return results.map((result, i) => {
    if (result.status === 'rejected') {
      logger.error(`Batch promise ${tasks[i].name} rejected with ${result.reason}`)
      return null
    }

    return result.value
  }) as T[] // I know this isn't right
}
```

I also want to give consumers the ability to explicitly type the Promise at invocation, which can look something like this.

```
const [hasPermission] = await runTasks([<Promise<boolean>>client.checkPermissions()])
```

Currently everything is coming back as `unknown`, but (especially when it's explicitly typed), I feel like the information I need is there, but I'm not well versed enough in generics to know how to access it. Is something like this possible?

Comment: Have you looked at the type declarations of `Promise.all` and `Promise.allSettled`?

Comment: "*The function takes in a list of Promises*" - then why did you declare `tasks: Array<Task<T>>`, which is a list of functions?

Comment: Also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/78074501/1048572

Comment: @Bergi that post may be what i'm looking for! I was scouring for hours and couldn't find anything related